# iPhone 5 Battery - Help me diagnose issue

Tags: iphone, battery

I'm having a weird issue with my iPhone 5, that I think is related to the battery, but might be something else.

### Symptoms

- The battery indicator is wrong. It sticks to the value it fetches when rebooting the phone. Currently, it shows 58% regardless that it's been charging for hours. If I reboot it, however, I get an accurate value, and it sticks to that one.
- I get the following error message in the Console when plugging it to Xcode:

```
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: partial sensors: count 5156, current 39fffe, mask 1b, expected 1b
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: Could not get event from temperature service
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: Could not get value for gas gauge battery
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: Could not get event from temperature service
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: Could not get value for gas gauge battery
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: Could not get event from temperature service
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: Could not get value for gas gauge battery
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: Could not get event from temperature service
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: Could not get value for gas gauge battery
    CLTM[14] : CLTM: partial sensors: count 5160, current 39fffe, mask 1b, expected 1b
```

The value in `partial sensors: count XX` increases as the iPhone runs.

- After rebooting, with the battery too charged or too discharged, the iPhone enters a reboot loop, where it will reboot every 5 minutes. Eventually, when the battery reaches 75% or so, it remains on. At that point, I can use it "normally", with a wrong battery indicator.

Here's the tricky thing: I live in Argentina where the iPhone is not officially for sale, and no authorised services are available. I got it when travelling to the US.

I can easily have the battery replaced (parts are available and not too expensive), but if it's not the battery (maybe the charging circuit?). Since the service is not authorised, however, I'm reluctant to have them open my iPhone if it won't solve the issue.

My question(s) therefore are:

- Did anyone experience something like this? If so, was the problem the battery?
- Does anyone know what `CLTM` in the Console log could mean?
- Is the battery level meter part of the battery itself (and therefore will be fixed when changing the battery) or is it a separate thing?

Comment: Before having the battery (hardware) replaced, have you restored the software on the iPhone? Try restoring through iTunes normally. If that doesn't work, try a DFU restore.

Comment: I tried it (normal and DFU restore), same deal. The Console log showed the same errors even during the setup screens that appear on you newly restored iPhone.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what happens if you replace the battery.

Comment: So far, nothing good: I replaced the battery with a local service guy, found via the local eBay, and now the phone doesn't turn the screen on, and when you plug it to the Mac it keeps repeating the "plugged in" sound.
It either was not the battery and something else, or the technician made a mistake and broke other things in the process (I tend to trust him, but anyone can make a mistake).

Comment: It's probably your fuel gauge- take it to a professional iPhone diagnostics shop, or Apple, it's not the battery, your fuel gauge Is unwell.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my iPhone 5 two years ago and it was simply due to the charging cycles number (battery was dying). I replaced it with a new one by myself and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It might not help the OP, but Apple has battery replacement program for iPhone 5. You can check eligibility on [Apple site](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone5-battery/other_countries.html)

> Apple has determined that a very small percentage of iPhone 5 devices may suddenly experience shorter battery life or need to be charged more frequently. The affected iPhone 5 devices were sold between September 2012 and January 2013 and fall within a limited serial number range.
>   (...)
>
> The program covers affected iPhone 5 batteries for two years after the first retail sale of the unit or until March 1, 2015, whichever provides longer coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the battery level meter is run by the chip. So I would think that the battery has corrupted the input going into the chip. From your explanation, I think that the battery was sold just with a series of logic boards in the battery slightly out of place, yet still running. Then the iPhone overheated the slightly defective wires slightly warped the battery with the heat. I would suggest getting the battery replaced.

Comment: What did I just read... go look up I2c interface and fuel gauges. That was a load of rubbish.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my iPhone 5 two years ago and it was simply due to the charging cycles number (battery was dying). I replaced it with a new one by myself and problem solved.